# Use of std::size_t in array function template header (C++)

Tags: c++, templates

In this code:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

//                       here
template <typename T, std::size_t size>
void printArray(const std::array<T, size>& myArray) {
    for (auto element : myArray)
        std::cout << element << ' ';
    std::cout << '\n';
}

int main() {
    std::array myArray1{ 9.0, 7.2, 5.4, 3.6, 1.8 };
    
    printArray(myArray1);
    // shouldn't this line be
    printArray<double, 5>(myArray1)

    return 0;
}
```

I understand how the template and function works, but what I don't understand is where `std::size_t` is being passed in on line 16. I know templates will deduce the type. Will it automatically pass in the array size, too?

Comment: i suppose the first step is to understand how this line works in details `std::array myArray1{ 9.0, 7.2, 5.4, 3.6, 1.8 };`. You know that this is actually `std::array<double,5> myArray1{ 9.0, 7.2, 5.4, 3.6, 1.8 };` ?

Comment: In many cases, if a function's template arguments are used for its argument types, those template arguments can be deduced based on what you pass to the function when you call it. See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction There must be a duplicate for this.

Comment: Template parameters, depending on the context, can be inferred.

Comment: `printArray` will deduce both `double` and `5` because both are contained in the type of `myArray1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know templates will deduce the type. Will it automatically pass in the array size, too?

Yes, the value of the template non-type parameter `size` will be deduced from the type of the function argument, same as the template type parameter `T` is deduced.